# Color nodes by Networkx node attribute with Bokeh

Tags: python, networkx, bokeh

I'm trying to use bokeh to create an interactive network visualization. I understand how to add attribtue data to the bokeh graph, but I'm not sure how to assign a fill color based on the node attribute.

I've been following all of the [bokeh examples](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html) that I can find, but I can't seem to figure it out.

**How can I adjust my code below to color the nodes by their NetworkX node attributes?**

```
import networkx as nx
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Circle, HoverTool, TapTool, BoxSelectTool
from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx

output_notebook()

# create a sample graph
G = nx.karate_club_graph()

# create the plot
plot = figure(x_range=(-1.1, 1.1), y_range=(-1.1, 1.1))

# add tools to the plot
plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("Name", "@name"), 
                                   ("Club", "@club")]), 
               TapTool(), 
               BoxSelectTool())

# create bokeh graph
graph = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, iterations=1000, scale=1, center=(0,0))

# add name to node data
graph.node_renderer.data_source.data['name'] = list(G.nodes())

# add club to node data
graph.node_renderer.data_source.data['club'] = [i[1]['club'] for i in G.nodes(data=True)]

# set node size
graph.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=10)

plot.renderers.append(graph)
show(plot)
```

[image: Bokeh Graph]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is a little vague, so I am not sure the code below is exactly what you are asking for. (Is the "node" attribute what you copy in to the "names" column? I think so...) But regardless, you can use [`linear_cmap`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/transform.html#bokeh.transform.factor_cmap) to colormap the `fill_color` according to any CDS column:

```
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap
graph.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(
    size=10, 
    fill_color=linear_cmap('name', 'Spectral8', min(G.nodes()), max(G.nodes()))
)
```

Alternatively if the column is string factors, you could also use `factor_cmap`.

[image]

Comment: The goal of my original question is to color the graph by the categorical node attribute `club`, not the node name.

Comment: Then for now you need to copy the attribute data to a column in the CDS by hand, then use the answer above.   There is an open Pull Request open to automatically add node and edge attributes to data sources that will be in the next release.

Comment: Cool!  Thanks for following up!

Comment: @CurtLH: You should consider upvoting or accepting this answer.

Comment: @bigreddot  is this now possible with the most recent version of bokeh?

Comment: It was possible before. If you are asking if attributes are now copied to CDS automatically, then yes, since many releases ago.